# How to shorten the repetitive code in this scenario

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using flutter, and I am making an appBar to position itself based on slider. I came up with the below code, As you can see, the slider code is repetitive. Is there any way I could shorten it?

I need to make this slider custom and do something like CustomSlider(appBarPosistion.height/top/left); So that my code won't repetitive.

```
class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  NewWidget(this.appBarPosistion);

  final AppBarPosistion appBarPosistion;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 100,
      ),
      Slider(
        value: appBarPosistion.height,
        min: 0,
        max: 0.5,
        divisions: 100,
        label: "Height " + appBarPosistion.height.toString(),
        onChanged: (value) => appBarPosistion.height = value,
      ),
      Slider(
          value: appBarPosistion.top,
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          divisions: 100,
          label: "Top " + appBarPosistion.top.toString(),
          onChanged: (value) => appBarPosistion.top = value),
      Slider(
          value: appBarPosistion.left,
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          divisions: 100,
          label: "Left " + appBarPosistion.left.toString(),
          onChanged: (value) => appBarPosistion.left = value),
      // CustomSlider(appBarPosistion.left, appBarPosistion: null,),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is max for `appBarPosition.height` 0.5?

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, the slider code is repetitive. Is there any way I could shorten it?

The code seems repetitive because of the similar type of work being done on `appBarPosition` Properties, but In my opinion, each and every one of the slider needs to be declared as they are in this code.

Above all things, even if I try to combine the common logic under one component it would still be similar to the existing code.

Check out following:

```dart
Widget _buildSlider({
    double Function() getPosition,
    void Function(double newPosition) setPosition,
    double max,
    String labelPrefix,
  }) {
    return Slider(
      value: getPosition(),
      min: 0,
      max: max,
      divisions: 100,
      label: "$labelPrefix ${getPosition()}",
      onChanged: (value) => setPosition(value),
    );
  }
```

usage:

```dart
_buildSlider(
        getPosition: () => appBarPosition.left,
        setPosition: (value) => appBarPosition.left,
        max: 100,
        labelPrefix: "Left"
      ),
_buildSlider(
        getPosition: () => appBarPosition.top,
        setPosition: (value) => appBarPosition.top,
        max: 100,
        labelPrefix: "Top"
      )
```

As you can see in the above example, I have to resort to passing getter & setter as parameter to update individual properties of the `appBarPostion` for following reasons:

- Each property being manipulated is of premitive type (double), hence can not be passed as a `reference`, must be passed as a `value`
- Each Slider updates different property of the `appBarPosition`.

Check out this code in dart pad to understand the pass by value problem in this code.
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/8fb0631a349a3d183a83111a65c512ae

**Conclusion:**

I'd say, There's no need to remove repitition of code in this case, as it's not actually repeating everything, but if you want to do it anyway then try the approach I suggested in `_buildSlider` method above.

Comment: Thank you Joshi. I have implemented what you suggested. I am having trouble again, that I can't move the slider. when I was making the call from outside, The slide has a state and I was able to move the slider. Now I couldn't. Could you please help me.

Comment: In that case, you should call `setState`  while updating any of the values using slider. I think what is happening is that slider is updating the values but since state is not updating, slider will be stuck at the initial state only. In other words, using `setState` inside the `setPosition` callback should resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `ListView.builder` and ternary operators.

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 3,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){

      return Slider(
        value: index == 0 ? appBarPosistion.height: index == 1 ? appBarPosistion.top : appBarPosistion.left,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        divisions: 100,
        label: index == 0 ? "Height " + appBarPosistion.height.toString() : index == 1 ? "Top"  + appBarPosistion.top.toString(): "Left"+ appBarPosistion.left.toString(),
        onChanged: (value) => index == 0 ? appBarPosition.height = value : index == 1 ? appBarPosition.top = value : appBarPosition.left = value,
      );

      }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks ASAD, I'll try this approach, and let you know if I have any trouble implementing them.

Comment: Sure, looking forward :)